# Adding OnClick event to a bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is all the code that I have, there is something wrong with the `"on click"` part that I couldn't figure out.
 It errors and says "**drill not defined"**
Isn't it the way we can call a method on click event of one of those bar charts that I am drawing in the D3 section?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    gon.data.pop(); // get rid of query_time element.
    var dataset = gon.data;

    function drill(d, i) {
        console.log(d.total_count); //data object
        var url = "http://localhost:4567/drill/" + d.brand_name + "/" + d.generic_name;
        window.location.href = url;
    }

    d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("onclick", "drill()")
        .style("height", function(d) {
            return d.brand_name + "px";
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your declaration of the `drill` function to outside of your document-ready handler.

Better still, use the `on` method that d3 provides, rather than the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. will try then now.

Comment: fixed it:)  IS there a reason I get this in the console?  The charts draw fine now but always getting this error in console:  "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined myfile.js:1
(anonymous function)"

Comment: You should ask that in a new question. Looks like an issue with jQuery not being available.

Answer (score 7):

To add event listeners to selections you should use selection's [on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on) method.

You can write

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .on("click", drill)
    .style("height", function(d) {
        return d.brand_name + "px";
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it:) IS there a reason I get this in the console? The charts draw fine now but always getting this error in console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined myfile.js:1 (anonymous function)"

Comment: Is your `<script>` jquery reference placed before the myfile.js reference?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use jQuery .click() if you want, here's an example

```
$("#test").click(function(){
     sayHello();   
});
```

jsfiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/SGRmX/1/

Comment: fixed it:) IS there a reason I get this in the console? The charts draw fine now but always getting this error in console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined myfile.js:1 (anonymous function)"

Comment: be sure to import jquery before your script, in the html file's <head>